# Xzing recognizes Barcode only in Java version

Tags: ruby, barcode, zxing

I'm trying to bulk scan some jpg files with barcodes on them. I've used the ruby bindings for the c++ port of xzing. When I have this file:

[image: barcode]
scanned by the Web-Version of Xzing (https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) everything turns out fine. When I try to scan this one in ruby (using https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing_cpp.rb) nothing is recognized. I already tried cranking up the contrast, but it did not help. It's not my ruby setup because it works for loads of other nearly identical codes. The only thing I can think of is any difference between the Java version and the C++ port, but this is absolute poking in the dark, I've started using zxing just today.
Could anyone get this code recognized in ruby? Thank you very much.

Comment: did you check out https://github.com/glassechidna/zxing_cpp.rb ?

Comment: Hi,
this is exactly the lib I've used, just edited my post, sorry

Comment: the gem has not been updated in a long time, I'm having trouble even installing the required ruby 1.9 to run it.  I suspect I would get the same result even if I did.  What happens if you desaturate the colors or try to crop out the non barcode portion of the image?

Comment: Hm, this is nothing that could be done automatically in a robust way, this is thought to be used in a script that runs about 2000 images a day, this is the maximum accuracy of the sticker position I can get. I will have a look into the jruby implementation, that one should be a newer implementation if I got everything right?

Comment: I got it wrong. The wrapper is 6 years old, too. Maybe ruby is just the wrong language for this project, just had a look into quagga. Seems like I have to search for my stuff from university, this was the last time I had to deal with Java... 
But thank you for your help very much!

Comment: I was able to convert the image to greyscale in terminal using image magick which the gem uses under the hood.  `convert QC3B1.jpg -set colorspace Gray -separate -average g.jpg` so you might play around with that to see iff you can get the images to be more readable?  But again just a guess. Sorry I couldn't get the old ruby 1.9 running to test the gem.  If I had more time I'd try with a docker container.

Comment: not sure if this might be useful https://github.com/Inlite/wabr-ruby

Comment: also try https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/ but got message  'The result contains not printable characters.' so that could be an encoding problem perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem you're using and/or it's dependencies our out of date.  If you want to still use Ruby for your project, you can try using one of the online services in the comments for the decoding.  You could either try to use the 
[mechanize gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize) or roll your own using other http ruby tools such as [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) or Ruby's [Net::HTTP](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)